# Configure extent reports for my Appium project

Tags: java, selenium, extentreports

```
package ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
public class ExtentManager {
    private static ExtentReports extent;
    public synchronized static ExtentReports getReporter() {
        if (extent == null) {
            String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("win")) {
                extent = new ExtentReports(workingDir + "\\ExtentReports\\ExtentReportResults.html", true);
            }
        }
        return extent;
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is :

> The constructor ExtentReports(String, boolean) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The constructor For Extent Reports will accept boolean parameter for append in version 2.XX only,

If you are update to Extent reports version 3 or above then you have to do it like this

> 

```
 ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("fileNamehere"); 
    htmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true);
 ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter );
```

You can find docs for all version here
[Extent Reports Documentation](http://extentreports.com/documentation/)

Comment: i move my version from 3 to 5 and the first line needed to change to
 ExtentSparkReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentSparkReporter("fileName");